# Revoked Certificate by Apple

Tags: ios, xcode

I submited my App to Apple and they responded that My certificate is Revoked .What does this mean?

Comment: I have had the same problem and found this answer all I needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689116/certificate-has-either-expired-or-has-been-revoked

Answer (score 0):

The app you submitted was code signed using a certificate which is revoked. 
You need to download new certificate, then it should show a private key associated with it in your keychain access once you install it. Then use this certificate as a code signing identity from your target > Build Setting > Code Signing Identity.