# Apple developer you're certificate has been revoked

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-sierra

Ok so I have found these three answers: This one [Revoked Certificate by Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584642/revoked-certificate-by-apple#autocomment70678749) this one [Your iOS Development certificate has been revoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294090/your-ios-development-certificate-has-been-revoked#autocomment70678676) and this one [Certificate has either expired or has been revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689116/certificate-has-either-expired-or-has-been-revoked) and I get the same problem (A email from apple) every time that I use Xcode on one of the macOS devices that I have and then switch over and use Xcode on one of the other macOS device or vice-versa. and I think I know what's going on according to the answer at [Your iOS Development certificate has been revoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294090/your-ios-development-certificate-has-been-revoked#autocomment70678676) but is there any way that I can stop this from happening every time that I switch and use Xcode on the other device without needing to go through the process explained here? [Certificate has either expired or has been revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689116/certificate-has-either-expired-or-has-been-revoked)

Comment: so just a comment I think whats going on is that a new certificate is being generated every time switch devises is that correct?

Comment: you should create your own developpement certificate in your account and add all test devices you use

Comment: you may need to share the `.p12` between the two computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing your mac, you have to create the .p12 file from certificate and install that .p12 onto new mac. Then there will be no problem regarding that certificate.

If you are familiar with how to create .p12 file from certificate.

Please check this link for certificate :-

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html
```

Comment: Im not familiar with .p12 files or how to create a development certificate or add test devices any advice of where to go to find that out?

Comment: @MikaelWeiss Please check this link and you will find how to create developer certificate.

Comment: What link? Thanks again for all the help : )

Comment: Sorry I just saw the link in the answer above.

Comment: one last question am I required to be a paid developer to do all this?

Comment: No, But if you want to publish your app on the app store. Then you have to be a paid developer.

Answer (score 1):

you should create your own developpement certificate in your account and add all test devices you use.

but if you change your mac you should move certificate to the other mac or just create a new certificate for this mac.

Comment: else your xcode will generate each time a new x.* certificate